# Variable name is content of another variable

Tags: string, variables, powershell

I have a list of variables:

```
$desa = "filtering regex for desa"
$cdo  = "different regex for cdo"
```

etc.

Now, I have a loop:

```
Foreach ($profilename in ("desa", "cdo")) {
  # filter out data from $profilename file where regex is contained in
  # variable named after the content of $profilename
}
```

So, in other words, I need to use a string contained in one of the variables at the top, and the name of that variable is the exact content of the `$profilename` variable.

Can PowerShell do this?

Comment: `Get-Variable` can get variable by name, but, I think, you better to use `Hashtable` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to us a hash table of regexes than separate variables for each one:

```
$filters = @{
desa = "filtering regex for desa"
cdo = "different regex for cdo"
}


Foreach ($profilename in
   ( "desa", "cdo")
)
  {
    (Get-content <profilename file>) -match $filters[$profilename] 
  }
```

Just name the keys after your profile names.

Comment: Thanks again for a swift and concise answer. One thing that is bugging me now is that for some reason, I can't get anything from that hash table; no matter what, output it System.Collections.Hashtable.xxx (xxx being the $profilename from above), rather than th relevant string. Since I am rather new to PowerShell, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried all sorts of variations when creating the hash table (with quotes around keys, without, with semi-colon after each pair, without, etc).

Comment: Post your script to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As [@mjolinor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31948519/1630171) said: hashtables are a better approach for this. However, if for some reason you must expand a "constructed" variable you can do it by using the `$ExecutionContext` [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

```
PS C:\> $a = 'foo'
PS C:\> $b = 'a'
PS C:\> $c = "`$$b"
PS C:\> $c
$a
PS C:\> $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($c)
foo
```

Applied to your code that might look like this:

```
$desa = "filtering regex for desa"
$cdo = "different regex for cdo"

foreach ($profilename in 'desa','cdo') {
  $pattern = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("`$$profilename")

  $something | ? { $_ -match $pattern } | ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. Although the $ExecutionContext does what I initially swet out to do, Hash table seems the best way to go. Now I am thinking of looping through the table itself, rather than using a separate array to loop through. That way, I avoid duplication and possible errors (from mismatching keys and objects in array).